# Automatically adjust targetsheetname to active sheet of targetspreadsheetID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have here a google script to transfer data to other google sheet. May I ask what are the adjustments should I make for targetSheetName to automatically adjust to what is the active sheet of the targetspreadsheet

```
function copySelectedRows() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  var targetSpreadsheetId = "TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  
  var sourceSheetName = "SourceSheetName";
  var targetSheetName = "TargetSheetName"
  
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  
  var selection = sourceSheet.getSelection();
  var selectedRanges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  
  var targetData = [];
  
  selectedRanges.forEach(function (range) {
    var startRow = range.getRow();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 4); // Assuming column B is index 2, column C is index 3, and column D is index 4
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    
    sourceValues.forEach(function (row) {
      targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3]]); // Copying values from column B, C, D to E, A, and F respectively
    });
  });
  
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetData.length, targetData[0].length); // Starting from column A (1)
  targetRange.setValues(targetData);
}
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the target sheet to the current active sheet you will need to bind and use the script on the target spreadsheet.
Then from there you can use the `getActiveSpreadsheet()` and `getActiveSheet()`.

**Try:**

```
function copySelectedRows() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = "SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID";
  
  var sourceSheetName = "SourceSheetName";
  
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  
  //Modified section --- START
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  // --- END
  var selection = sourceSheet.getSelection();
  var selectedRanges = selection.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  
  var targetData = [];
  
  selectedRanges.forEach(function (range) {
    var startRow = range.getRow();
    var numRows = range.getNumRows();
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 4); // Assuming column B is index 2, column C is index 3, and column D is index 4
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    
    sourceValues.forEach(function (row) {
      targetData.push([row[0], "", "", row[1], row[2], row[3]]); // Copying values from column B, C, D to E, A, and F respectively
    });
  });
  
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, targetData.length, targetData[0].length); // Starting from column A (1)
  targetRange.setValues(targetData);
}
```

Comment: I just noticed the subject of this post is saying sourcesheetname but the actual details in the question says targetsheet. Please clarify. Let me know if the answer posted works for you! So we can adjust it.

Comment: Apologies. I edited the subject. Do i need to retain targetSpreadsheetID?  This script is intended to automatically paste from the sourcespreadsheetID to the targetspreadsheetID. However, on the target spreadsheet, everyday we add new sheet and hide the sheet from the previous day. So i need the script to automatically paste the info to the active sheet of the targetspreadsheetID (wherever my cursor is placed within targetspreadsheetID). Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You dont need to retain the targetSpreadsheetID, since the targetSpreadsheet is already set to = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(). This will get the current spreadsheet it is bound to. Also I think it should work on your scenario to automatically run

Answer (score 0):

You can use get Active:

```
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getÁctive()
```